# apache alias error subfolders access

Tags: apache

I have WAMP server 2.2

I created a test php project (2 php files) in my test folder, the test folder is located at: c:\projects\test\

I added an alias to apache, and the conf file is this:

```
Alias /test "c:\projects\test\" 

<Directory "c:\projects\test/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny 
        Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

I added a new folder under test, full path is: **c:\projects\test\img**

My issue is that I cannot access from http any file located under this folder. Do I have to add some extra line in conf file? What is wrong? I'd like to be able to access any file in any subfolder of my root folder (c:\projects\test).

Thank you.